# functions not returning variable

Tags: php

I'm having some issue with two functions at the moment; I'm trying to get an array to pass from the first function to the other--but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

```
    function getResourceXML($id)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('resources.xml');
    foreach($xml->children()->children() as $children)
    {
        if($children['id'] == $id)
        {
            $resource[] = $children["income"];
            return $resource;
        }
    }   
}
function getResourceMultiplier()
{
    $sql = "SELECT resourceArray FROM starinformation WHERE starOwner = :uid";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('uid', $this->uid);
    try 
    {
        $que->execute();
        while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
        {
            $resource = $this->getResourceXML($row[0]);
            return $resource;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {}
}
```

Comment: Are these being used inside a class? You're `$this` but didn't provide the class code here

Comment: @helion3 yes they are.. SOrry, half a sleep should've mentioned that

Comment: Are you debugging the output? The return values are conditional so if a condition fails, you won't see it. Also, you have a `return` inside a while loop, which means it'll only run once

Comment: `$row[0]`? Should it not be just `$row`?

Comment: _"trying to get an array to pass"_ is that a typo, because you are not passing an array your passing an array element.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yah sorry, that was a typo

Comment: The first function is returning an array

Comment: If you're building an array, shouldn't your return be out of the loop?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your fundamental knowledge of PHP I suggest reading the docs again.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `return` statement to after the loop `}` in both functions or else you only get one loop iteration.  Also, in `getResourceMultiplier()` you're not creating an array.  You need (or similar):

```
$resource[] = $this->getResourceXML($row[0]);
```